# How to capture images using camera in Android without user interaction or pressing on screen? I want to make a spy app

Tags: android, camera, image-capture

How to capture image/ images secretly using camera without user interaction? I want to make a spy app so that it can take image/ images without any user interaction? 
Is it possible? Please someone help me.

Comment: Ethics of creating such an app aside, this question is too broad for the scope of SO. Please take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
private void takePhoto()
{
    SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(this);
        Camera camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null,null,jpegCallback);
}



PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
{
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
  String dir_path = "";// set your directory path here
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(dir_path+File.separator+image_name+no_pics+".jpg");    
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally 
    {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;


    }
}
};
```